# Error when opening Google Drive

Tags: windows-7, windows, google-drive

For a few days now I am getting this error every time I open Google Drive in my PC.

[image]

I tried re-installing but still get the same error.

Do you have an idea what's causing this?

Comment: This could be caused by MalWare since  other internet users are reporting *similar*... Please run a complete AV check for virus/malware/etc

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by improper date set on your computer. Make sure that you have date and time set to current date.

Answer (score 0):

Try Right-clicking the installer and running it as admin. Make sure your date is Current as-well like [IMB](https://superuser.com/users/80762/imb) suggested.

Also, Security essentials has been know to cause issues try these steps they may help

1. Uninstall security essentials.
2. Uninstall Google Drive.
3. Reinstall Google Drive as Admin & assign it to a new directory so everything downloads again.

After doing all that try not to make it a habit to uninstalling and re-installing also you may want to not use Microsoft security essentials.

I hope this helped if not leave a comment and I will see what I can do.